# Rails - Don't repeat yourself on scope definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many

Here is a sample model :

```
class Book < AR::Base
  has_many :pages

  scope :with_some_conditions, ->(var) {
    where(... something with var ...)
    .joins(... some joins ...)
  }
end

class Page << AR::Base
  # Attrs : a, b (integers)
  belongs_to :book

  scope :with_c, {
    select("#{Page.table_name}.*, (a+b) AS c")
  }

  def c; a+b; end
end
```

I'm tring to get the 10 `pages` with the biggest `c` value, belongs to `books` respecting some conditions.

This code is working :

```
Book.with_some_conditions('foo').map(&:pages).map(&:c)[0...10]
```

Or better

```
Book.with_some_conditions('foo').includes(:pages).map(&:pages).map(&:c)[0...10]
```

Now imagine that the `c` method is not a simple method as `+`, but it's a **really** more complicated function (with joins and some other things). This code is simply unoptimized as possible... All `c` must be computed and ordered in Rails... SQL can be helpful.

Defining a scope in `Page` model is the better solution I found :

```
scope :big_scope, ->(var) {
  joins(:book)
  .where(... something with var ...) # The 2 lines are C/P from Book model
  .joins(... some joins ...)
  .select("#{Page.table_name}.*, (a+b) AS c")
}
```

Then, call `Page.big_scope('foo').order(:c => :desc)` works perfectly.

The problem is I'm repeating myself : the complete scope is written 2 times in 2 different classes.

```
  .where(... something with var ...)
  .joins(... some joins ...)
```

Is there any method to "call" a scope through a relation ?

Regards

Comment: A common way to deal with repetition is to put the code in a module and include the module in both classes.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Howto include "scopes" from 2 different classes into a module ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the standard module 'template' i use if i want to share methods between two or more classes.

```
module MyModule
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
    base.class_eval do 
      #associations, callbacks, scopes, validations etc go here
    end
  end

  #instance methods go here

  module ClassMethods
    #class methods go here
  end    
end
```